# ! Missing $ inserted. -or- Display should end with $$

Tags: math-mode, errors, equations, amsmath

```
\begin{equation}
\label{observer position}
\textbf{R_\textbf{n}}  =\left [\frac{R_e}{\sqrt{1-(2f-f^2)sin^2 \phi_n}}+H_n\right]cos\phi_n(cos\theta_n \hat{\textbf{I}}+sin\theta_n\hat{\textbf{J}})+\left[\frac{R_e(1-f)^2}{\sqrt{1-(2f-f^2)sin^2 \phi_n}}+H_n\right] sin\phi_n\hat{\textbf{K}} \nonumber \\
\end{equation}
```

this is my code.  I am using ams math and have tried `\[\]` and `$$` before and after the line.  It still keeps giving the error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The only way to get this to run is with \protect.

Comment: Besides campa's comment: The equation is too wide for a standard text setup, most likely. And `$$` is deprecated.

Comment: Why use `\nonumber` in an `equation` environment instead of using an `equation*` environment? And why a `\label` in an un-numbered environment that you can never meaningfully refer to?

Answer (score 6):

While `\textbf` is allowed in math mode, you're misusing it: remember that its argument is typeset in text mode anyway, so `_` in it is wrong.

However, for the usage you're making of it, `\mathbf` is better.

The formula is too long to fit on one line; using `\nonumber` together with `\label` doesn't make much sense.

You can use `multline`; I present two versions, one with a refinement in order to get a less prominent square root sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\mathbf{R}_{n}=
  \biggl[
    \frac{R_e}{\sqrt{1-(2f-f^2)\sin^2 \phi_n}}+H_n
  \biggr]
  \cos\phi_n(\cos\theta_n \hat{\mathbf{I}}+\sin\theta_n\hat{\mathbf{J}})\\
  +
  \biggl[
    \frac{R_e(1-f)^2}{\sqrt{1-(2f-f^2)\sin^2 \phi_n}}+H_n
  \biggr]
  \sin\phi_n\hat{\mathbf{K}}
\end{multline*}

\begin{multline*}
\mathbf{R}_{n}=
  \biggl[
    \frac{R_e}{\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-(2f-f^2)\sin^2 \phi_n}}}+H_n
  \biggr]
  \cos\phi_n(\cos\theta_n \hat{\mathbf{I}}+\sin\theta_n\hat{\mathbf{J}})\\
  +
  \biggl[
    \frac{R_e(1-f)^2}{\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-(2f-f^2)\sin^2 \phi_n}}}+H_n
  \biggr]
  \sin\phi_n\hat{\mathbf{K}}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need a boldface “n” as the subscript to “R” in the left hand side, the correct syntax would be

```
\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{n}}
```

Yet another solution implementing a suggestion by Barbara Beeton:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sin}{%
  \@ifnextchar^%
    {\operatorname{\smash{\mathrm{sin}}\vphantom{s}}}%
    {\operatorname{sin}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\mathbf{R}_{n}=
  \biggl[
    \frac{R_e}{\sqrt{1-(2f-f^2)\sin^2 \phi_n}}+H_n
  \biggr]
  \cos\phi_n(\cos\theta_n \hat{\mathbf{I}}+\sin\theta_n\hat{\mathbf{J}})\\
  +
  \biggl[
    \frac{R_e(1-f)^2}{\sqrt{1-(2f-f^2)\sin^2 \phi_n}}+H_n
  \biggr]
  \sin\phi_n\hat{\mathbf{K}}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

If the `\sin` operator is followed by `^`, we smash the “i”; otherwise we don't.

[image]

Comment: Maybe `\bm{n}`, don't you think?

Comment: @Bernard There are several possibilities, but as a simple n is in the right-hand side, I think it should be simple also in the left-hand side.

Comment: I meant, in case a boldface  n is required.

Comment: @Bernard Even in that case it could be `\mathbf{n}`; it mostly depends on the conventions of the field the OP belongs to.

Comment: You're certainly right. I confess  I don't like variables in upshape, but that's an aesthetic prejudice…

Comment: the "less prominent" square root sign is a little "more less" than optimal -- there's a root of an intermediate size that's being ignored here.  if one is *really* fussy, applying just `\smash{\sin}^2` will lower that superscript (by ignoring the extra height imposed by the dot on the "i"), at which point the "mid-sized" root will kick in.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your wish is my command!

Comment: oh, that looks *much* nicer!  thank you!  (you've earned your +1.)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you split your equation in two, using an `alignedat` environment. I suppose the boldface subscript `n` should be `bolditalic`. I also replaced `\hat` with `\widehat`, as I think the former is too small for boldface letters. Finally, I don't see why you have a label, but not number for cross-references.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{observer position} \nonumber
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    \mathbf{R}_{\boldsymbol{n}} & = & \left [\frac{R_e}{\sqrt{1-(2f-f^2)\sin^2 \phi_n}}+H_n\right]\cos\phi_n(\cos\theta_n \widehat{\mathbf{I}}+\sin\theta_n\widehat{\mathbf{J}}) & \\
    & & +\left[\frac{R_e(1-f)^2}{\sqrt{1-(2f-f^2)\sin^2 \phi_n}}+H_n\right] \sin\phi_n\widehat{\mathbf{K}} &
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]